# C++(MFC) - Dialog shadow afterimage

Tags: mfc

`.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`

Hiding the dialog leaves a shadow.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Where exactly?...

Comment: Interesting. Is it a modal or modeless dialog?

Comment: it`s modeless dialog.

Comment: That shadow looks very strange. Do you have some special sofware that "enhances" your windows look? Do you have the problem on owhter computers as well? Does closing the dialog leave a shadow as well?

Comment: Maybe you have added `CS_DROPSHADOW` to your dialog/window class and the parent is not invalidated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Because of CS_DROPSHADOW...
Removed 'CS_DROPSHADOW'  and it works normally. thank you!